# Generating a non-uniform 1D mesh in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, mesh

I am trying to generate a non-uniform 1D mesh with constant stretching by a value r between 0 and 1.

This is the code I've tried but I can't seem to get this to work. The final value is never 1 and I'm not sure if this is because the number of indices needs to change so that the total distance remains the same. I'm new to this, I've never had to make any kind of unstructured mesh before so any help would be really great!

```
n = 20;    % number of indices
h = 1/(n-1);    % unstretched grid spacing
r = .9;       % stretching factor

x2 = zeros(n,1);
for i=2:n
    x2(i) = x2(i-1)+r^(i-2)*h;
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to place `n` nodes in geometric progression between `0` and `1` with ratio `r`, then the nodes will be placed at

```
x(1) = 0
x(2) = h
x(3) = h + r*h
x(4) = h + r*h + r^2*h
...
x(n) = h*(1 + r + r^3 + ... + r^(n-2)) = 1
```

where we can determine `h` as

```
h = 1/sum(r^j, j = 0..(n-2)) = (r - 1)/(r^(n-1) - 1)
```

We can then place all `n` nodes:

```
h = (r - 1)/(r^(n-1) - 1); % 1st grid spacing
x = [0, h*cumsum(r.^(0:(n-2)))];
```

Solution for `n = 5` and `r = 0.9`:

```
x = 
0.00000   0.29078   0.55249   0.78802   1.00000
```